# What reason could there be for a method not to work in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, methods, netbeans

I received the coding for a school project and I copied it into the source code for my Frame in Netbeans IDE and I have this error here:

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjIU1.png)

Why would a method like getText() not work?

Edit: [This is the code for the entire frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhKvv.png)

Comment: You need to post more of your actual code to get a definitive answer

Comment: It's also unlikely that this has anything to do with NetBeans

Comment: I've added the entire code for the frame. And you're right, it has nothing to do with NetBeans. id is in fact a text field, and I've never experienced this error before. What is the solution?

Comment: You still haven't added all of your code. Specifically, what type is `id`?

Comment: Actually it is a rather long-ish program consisting of many frames. Specifically it is a school project on Airline Reservation System. id is a the variable name for a text field. My doubt is: why is it being considered an object?

Answer (score 0):

`id` is an `Object` and there is no `getText()` method in the [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class of the API.